# Check how many rows retrieved in PostgreSQL (node.js)

Tags: postgresql, node.js

I would like to know how can you check the row count of the query in PostgreSQL in node.js
I have this code for the meantime.

```
    var client = new pg.Client(conString);
    client.connect();
    var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM users"); 
    query.on('row', function(row) {
      console.log(row);
    });
```

Comment: thanks for editing Milen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var client = new pg.Client(conString);

client.connect();

client.query("SELECT * FROM users", function(err, result) {
    console.log("Row count: %d",result.rows.length);  // n
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Another options is to use the `rowCount` property! Like this:

```
var pg = require('pg');

var pgClient = new pg.Client();
pgClient.connect();

var pgQuery = pgClient.query("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables;");
pgQuery.on('error', function(err) {
    pgClient.end();
    console.error(err);
});
pgQuery.on('end', function(result) {
    pgClient.end();
    console.log(result.rowCount);
});
```

or like this:

```
var pg = require('pg');

var pgClient = new pg.Client();
pgClient.connect();

var pgQuery = pgClient.query("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables;", function(err, result) {
    pgClient.end();
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(result.rowCount);
});
```